# Mail merge or merge-like functionality from C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, mailmerge

I need to print a few thousand stickers with a few text fields (name, position, etc) as well as a barcode image.

Each staff member gets two unique stickers, and the sticker paper has 4 per sheet so that's 2 staff per sheet.

I already have all the code to generate the barcode as an `Image`, and the staff details are stored in a `List` of object.

If possible, I'd like to avoid using MSWord directly since my development environment is quite different from the target environment and I've had issues in the past from the disparity. (Win7-64, MSOffice2010 vs. WinXP-32, MSOffice2003).

What's the best way to accomplish this?

If I save the document as an XML format and replace the mail merge fields with unique tokens which I can replace with my actual values (and I can even replace the binary image data with base-64 encoded image bytes) then that works but it's clunky. For starters, I'd have to save the XML file and then somehow print it transparent to the user (don't want Word showing up). Also, the XML template is 1 page, but I might have several dozen to print. I can send each page to the printer individually but that's not exactly ideal.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would use DevXpress XtraReports as I have used it in the past in similar scenarios with great results. If you prefer other engines like Crystal or Telerik is the same, as easy as dragging some fields in the page details section and assign your object list as datasource. DevXpress has also a RichTextBox with builtin mailmerge feature. at last if you decide for word do not forget that you can automate and use it while keeping it invisible so users wont see it.